# OData get URI of individual Entity

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I'm developing in SAPUI5 and I'm retrieving an EntitySet via an OData read function. My code looks like this:

```
oDataModel.read("/Products", {
    success: function(oData) {

        oData.results.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
            *// Here I want to get the Request URI for this specific element*
        });

    }
});
```

In the forEach function I want to retrieve the URI for the specific Entity from the EntitySet.

So for example I want to retrieve the URI like this:

> "/Products(ID='1')"
>   "/Products(ID='2')"

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply get the URL by creating it with the Entity Key values.

```
oDataModel.read("/Products", {
    success: function(oData) {

        oData.results.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
            var sEntity = "/Products(ID='"+element.ID+"')";
        });

   }
});
```

Comment: So there is no "build in" function to retrieve the URI?

Comment: Not with the Model read function. If you have an aggregation binding to some control, you could get the URI from the binding context for each child control.